# How do I redirect requests to appropriate websites without specifying their ports using nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, webserver

I have 2 websites (Using docker, deployed on a digital ocean droplet). I'm currently able to access both websites individually by the ports specified in the docker compose file like this:

```
    ports:
      - "3001:443"
```

Now the issue is that I would like to have users not have to enter the ports manually (like redirecting the requests to port 80/443 automatically) but since I have nginx running on my droplet I can't use port 80 for any requests that may come to my websites via port 80, and I can only have one website making use of 443, when I bring up the other website I get an error because 443 is used by another website.

So in short, I'd want to access both websites directly via either http/https just by their domain name only, but unsure on how to do this properly.

This is the nginx conf on my droplet that listens to requests for each website.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    location ~ ^/(api) {
            proxy_pass http://example-backend:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name demo.com;

    location ~ ^/(api) {
            proxy_pass http://demo-backend:9090;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

And this is the docker compose file for one of my websites

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  example-backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: ${MYSQL_DB_USER}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO: update
      SPRING_MAIL_USERNAME: ${SPRING_MAIL_USERNAME}
      SPRING_MAIL_PASSWORD: ${SPRING_MAIL_PASSWORD}

  // This is an NGINX container with the static content placed inside after building
  example-frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "3001:443"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - example-backend
    volumes:
      - ./web/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./web/dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - ./web/certbot/data:/usr/share/nginx/html/letsencrypt
      - ./web/certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl
```

Lastly, the nginx conf file for this specific website

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/letsencrypt;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com:3001$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     server_name example.com;

     server_tokens off;
     ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
     ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam-2048.pem;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://example-backend:8080;
    }

}
```

So now I can access the website after bringing up the containers, only at https://example.com:3001, http requests (using port 80) don't work because i already have nginx running on port 80 within my droplet/vps.

Similar thing for the second website, it's just that I'm using a different port instead of 3001

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is because all your server block share the same `server_name` i think.
You can use nginx to forward incoming http request on port 80 and 433 to be redirected to your containers. To do so, nginx use the `Host` headers from an http request to make it match with the `server_name`.

You should try something like this:

```
server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     listen 80;
     server_name example.com;

     server_tokens off;
     ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
     ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam-2048.pem;


    if ($scheme != 'https') {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/letsencrypt;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:3001;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://example-backend:8080;
    }
}
```

I'll recommand you to give a try to [nanocl](https://docs.next-hat.com/guides/nanocl) to deploy containers!

If you need futher help you can add me on discord you can find it on my profile

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added you on discord.